# WebRTC : navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia not working in Chrome on Android

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, webrtc, simple-peer

While I am working on basic React example with WebRTC (simple-peer)  :

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then(stream => {
      setStream(stream);
      if (userVideo.current) {
        userVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
      }
    })
```

I get the error as below :

[image]

I see that navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is compatible with Chrome on android so I wonder what causes this issue here. Kindly help on this.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. The mobile browser hasn't asked about permissions. Just try it on **Secure Connection** (ie: https, SSL).

Comment: This is just a small proof of concept  not sure how I could serve this over https

Comment: @RajeevAkotkar search how to enable this for http `How to enable mediaDevices for http`

Comment: you can establish a (free) https tunnel using https://ngrok.com

Answer (score 1):

Whiltelist your server by opening `chrome://flags` and search for `unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`:

`chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`

and add your server name `http://foobar`, relaunch chrome.

**NOTE**

This should be used only for testing!!!